# Remove items from list if not existing in a comparison list

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

In my fiddle you can copy items from a list to another, there also is a duplicated list that holds ordinary items, used for comparison. As it is now you are able to remove all items in the second list, but i only want to be able to remove those items that not exist in that one that holds ordinary items.

Code looks like this:

```
var SProcsViewModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.storedProceduresInDB1 = ko.observableArray([{
    Name: "Sp1",
    Id: 1
   }, {
       Name: "Sp2",
       Id: 2
   }, {
       Name: "Sp3",
       Id: 3
   }, {
       Name: "Sp4",
       Id: 4
   }]);
   self.storedProceduresInDB2Orig = ko.observableArray([{
       Name: "Sp3",
       Id: 3
   }, {
       Name: "Sp4",
       Id: 4
   }, {
       Name: "Sp7",
       Id: 7
   }, {
       Name: "Sp8",
       Id: 8
   }]);
   self.storedProceduresInDB2 = ko.observableArray([{
       Name: "Sp3",
       Id: 3
   }, {
       Name: "Sp4",
       Id: 4
   }, {
       Name: "Sp7",
       Id: 7
   }, {
       Name: "Sp8",
       Id: 8
   }]);

   self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1 = ko.observableArray();
   self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb2 = ko.observableArray();

   self.copyToDb2 = function () {
       var sprocs = [];
       console.log('self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1()', self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1());
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function (value) {
        // console.log('arrayForEach',value,self.storedProceduresInDB2);
          var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.storedProceduresInDB2(), function (item) {
              console.log('item in storedProceduresInDB2', value, item);
              return value.Id === item.Id;
          });

          if (!match) {
            console.log('No match, so add to sprocs', value);
            sprocs.push(value);
          } else {
            console.log('Match found for:', value);
          }
       });

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function (value) {
        console.log('storedProceduresInDB1', value);
    });


    console.log('sprocs', sprocs);

    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.storedProceduresInDB2, sprocs)
   };

   self.removeFromDb2 = function(item, event){       
       self.storedProceduresInDB2.remove(function(item) {
           return item.Name == $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").text();
       });
   }

   return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new SProcsViewModel());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ue34N/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `ko.utils.arrayFirst` you can check that the clicked item is in the original list (`storedProceduresInDB2Orig`).

If the `ko.utils.arrayFirst` returns something then you just need to `return false` in your `remove` callback and your item won't be removed:

```
self.removeFromDb2 = function(item, event){       
    self.storedProceduresInDB2.remove(function(item) {
        var nameToRemove = $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").text();
        var isInOrig = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.storedProceduresInDB2Orig(), 
            function(item){
                return item.Name == nameToRemove;
        });
        if (isInOrig)
            return false;

        return item.Name == nameToRemove;
    });
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrqyR/).